# How to create a REST link pointing to /profiles/{user-id}/job URI using Spring EntityLinks?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I have a controller method which is responsible to return some data along with the useful links for the client app.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{uniqueId}")
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
public HttpEntity<UserProfileMinimalDto> getUserMinimal(@PathVariable String uniqueId) {
    UserProfileMinimalDto userDto = userProfileService.getProfileMinimal(uniqueId);
    userDto.add(
            entityLinks.linkToSingleResource(UserProfileController.class, uniqueId),
            linkTo(methodOn(UserJobController.class).getUserJobs(uniqueId)).withRel(REL_EXPERIENCES)
    );
```

The another controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(PROFILES)
@ExposesResourceFor(UserJob.class)
public class UserJobController {

    @PostMapping(value = "/{uniqueId}"+"/job" )
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public HttpEntity<UserJob> getUserJobs(@PathVariable String uniqueId) {
        System.out.println("user jobs");
        return new ResponseEntity<UserJob>(new UserJob(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

This return me the links:

```
"_links": {
    "self": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8085/api/v1/profiles/theCoder"
    },
    "experiences": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8085/api/v1/profiles/theCoder/job"
    }
}
```

But I want to achieve same results using `EntityLinks`. As one can see I have exposed `UserJobController` as a `UserJob` resource so that I can use it with `EntityLinks`
So I tried below methods but none of them worked.

```
entityLinks.linkFor(UserJob.class, uniqueId).withRel(REL_EXPERIENCES),
entityLinks.linkFor(UserJob.class, uniqueId, "/job").withRel(REL_EXPERIENCES)
```

But both of them return

```
"experiences": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8085/api/v1/profiles"
        }
```

What am I doing wrong here? Or `EntityLinks` are not meant to be used this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the right API to use. Here is one possible solution.

`entityLinks.linkFor(UserJob.class, uniqueId).slash("/job").withRel(REL_EXPERIENCES)`

Note: I don't want to use controller methods.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of providing links to a single resource (`linkToSingleResource`), try to link onto a specific method instead:

```
Link link = linkTo(methodOn(UserJobController.class).getUserJobs("theCoder")).withSelfRel();
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/reference/html/#fundamentals.obtaining-links.builder.methods

Comment: `methodOn` is applied for controllers, not for the entities or `@ExposesResourceFor`